# The result of json.loads(string) is still a string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm currently trying to build a database using Python 3.6 (under Spyder) and more precisely sqlite3 (3.14.2). Since this last module wasn't designed to enable list insertion in the database, i'm using the json (2.0.9) module to transform my lists into strings. The following function, used to transfer data from a database to another, and where I create and insert list for the first time, returns me weird results :

```
def database_concatenation():
    global log,name2,name3,timefin,path
    conn = sqlite3.connect(path+name2)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    conn2 = sqlite3.connect(path+name3)
    cursor2 = conn2.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select sqlite_version()""")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM {}""".format(name2))
    for dataline in cursor.fetchall():
        cursor2.execute("""
                       SELECT * FROM {} 
                   WHERE (
                   timestp = ?
                   AND idq = ?
                   AND idz = ?
                   AND portq = ?
                   AND portz = ?
                   AND prot = ?);
                   """.format(name3) , (dataline[0],dataline[1],dataline[2],dataline[3],dataline[4],dataline[5]))
        result = cursor2.fetchone()

        if result == None:
            with open(path+log,"a") as login:

                login.write(timefin + " Warning ! Unusual connection :" + str(dataline)+ '\n')


            cursor2.execute("""
                       INSERT INTO {}(timestp,
                       idq,
                       idz,
                       portq,
                       portz,
                       prot,
                       Leftmean,
                       Leftstdev,
                       Leftmean10,
                       Leftstdev10,
                       Rightmean,
                       Rightstdev,
                       Rightmean10,
                       Rightstdev10,
                       nbdays) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);""".format(name3), (dataline[0],dataline[1],dataline[2],dataline[3],dataline[4],dataline[5],dataline[6],0,json.dumps([dataline[6]]),0,dataline[7],0,json.dumps([dataline[7]]),0,1))

        else:
            print(result[8])
            Leftmean10 = json.loads(result[8])
            print(Leftmean10)
            Rightmean10 = json.loads(result[12])
            print(type(Leftmean10))

            nbdays = result[14]
            aL,bL = intervalle_confiance(result[6],result[7],result[14])
            aL10,bL10 = intervalle_confiancebis(Leftmean10,result[9],min(nbdays,10))
            aR,bR = intervalle_confiance(result[10],result[11],result[14])
            aR10,bR10 = intervalle_confiancebis(Rightmean10,result[13],min(nbdays,10))
            rhwmny = dataline[7]
            lhwmny = dataline[6]





        if nbdays >= 10:
            Leftmean10.pop(0)
            Rightmean10.pop(0)
            Leftmean10.append(dataline[6])
            Rightmean10.append(dataline[7])
            Lmean = result[6]
            Lmean = Lmean*(nbdays/(nbdays+1)) + dataline[6]/(nbdays)
            Rmean = result[10]
            Rmean = Rmean*(nbdays/(nbdays+1)) + dataline[7]/(nbdays)
            Lstdev,Rstdev = result[7],result[11]



            add = (dataline[6] - Lmean)
            Lstdev = sqrt(Lstdev*Lstdev + (add*add))
            add = (dataline[7] - Rmean)
            Rstdev = sqrt(Rstdev*Rstdev + (add*add))
            mean = (sum(Leftmean10)/min(10,nbdays))
            meansquare = mean*mean

            othermean = (sum([i*i for i in Leftmean10])/min(10,nbdays))
            Lstdev10 = othermean - meansquare


            mean = (sum([int(i) for i in Rightmean10])/min(10,nbdays))
            meansquare = mean*mean

            othermean = (sum([i*i for i in Rightmean10])/min(10,nbdays))
            Rstdev10 = othermean - meansquare

            nbdays +=1

            Leftmean10 = json.dumps(result[8])
            Rightmean10 = json.dumps(result[12])
            print(Leftmean10)

            cursor2.execute("""UPDATE {} SET Leftmean = ?,
                   Leftstdev = ?,
                   Leftmean10 = ?,
                   Leftstdev10 = ?,
                   Rightmean = ?,
                   Rightstdev = ?,
                   Rightmean10 = ?,
                   Rightstdev10 = ?,
                   nbdays = ?  WHERE (timestp = ? AND idq = ?
                   AND idz = ?
                   AND portq = ?
                   AND portz = ?
                   AND prot = ?);""".format(name3), (Lmean,Lstdev,Leftmean10,Lstdev10,Rmean,Rstdev,Rightmean10,Rstdev10,nbdays,result[0],result[1],result[2],result[3],result[4],result[5]))




    conn.commit()
    conn2.commit()
    conn.close()
    conn2.close()
    bla= "it works"

    return(bla)
```

When i launch it for the first time (base "name3" created but empty), the condition "if result = None" is always verified, and the database is correctly filled. Especially, my list is successfully stocked, using the function `json.dumps(mylist)`
The problem happens while processing a second time : the block

```
print(result[8])
Leftmean10 = json.loads(result[8])
print(Leftmean10)
Rightmean10 = json.loads(result[12])
print(type(Leftmean10))
```

returns

```
"[69]"
[69]
<class 'str'>
```

I furthermore get later errors because of this `'str'` type.

I don't understand what is happening. The `json.loads` function should returns a list, doesn't it ? And that's what it seems to do : `print(Leftmean10)` returns me `[69]`and not `"[69]"`, except.. It's for the program still a string ^^

Thank you in advance for answers !

Comment: Well it is a **JSON string**. So it is the correct output. One can write a string that contains the characters `'[', '6',...`.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't completely understand your comment x) ! For me was `json.loads("[2,3]")` returning `[2,3]` and not ['[','2',',','3",']'] like list("[2,3]") would x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string `result[8]` actually contains the double quote characters in them:

```
>>> print('[69]')
[69]
>>> print('"[69]"')
"[69]"
```

Inside `json.loads` this is correctly converted to the string `"[69]"`. One way to fix this is by removing these two double quotes:

```
json.loads(result[8][1:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works, but only partially.. I have another problem now, on the same theme x) ! But you still answered my question !